# Convert a column with categorical data to separate column for each category and transpose variable data of corresponding columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

I have a pandas dataframe with 60,000 rows and following format:

| date | type | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-02-02 | A | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2021-02-02 | B | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 2021-02-02 | C | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I am trying to transpose the variable numeric data in the hour columns (1-24) to rows, and split the "Type" column into separate column for each type (A,B,C):

| date | hour | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 6 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 7 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | 8 | 0.3 | 3 |
| 2021-02-02 | 1 | 6 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | 2 | 7 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 2021-02-02 | 3 | 8 | 0.3 | 3 |

I have looked at pivot, transpose and melt but not getting the result that I am looking for.
Could you please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), as follows:

```
(df.pivot('date', 'type')
   .stack(level=0)
   .rename_axis(index=['date', 'hour'], columns=None)
).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
         date hour    A    B    C
0  2021-01-01    1  6.0  0.1  1.0
1  2021-01-01    2  7.0  0.2  2.0
2  2021-01-01    3  8.0  0.3  3.0
3  2021-02-02    1  6.0  0.1  1.0
4  2021-02-02    2  7.0  0.2  2.0
5  2021-02-02    3  8.0  0.3  3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `set_index` + `unstack` and `stack`

```
out = df.set_index(['date','type']).rename_axis('hour',axis=1).stack().unstack(level=1).reset_index()
Out[140]: 
type        date hour    A    B    C
0     2021-01-01    1  6.0  0.1  1.0
1     2021-01-01    2  7.0  0.2  2.0
2     2021-01-01    3  8.0  0.3  3.0
3     2021-02-02    1  6.0  0.1  1.0
4     2021-02-02    2  7.0  0.2  2.0
5     2021-02-02    3  8.0  0.3  3.0
```

Comment: @AnuragDabas you can add the rename-axis before stack ~

Comment: @AnuragDabas happy coding ~